# Auto Update stock in Database Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I need to know about one thing in databases.
I have product table with it's total inventory as seen in image

[image]

If any one have any idea that how can i do that??
Please Share it
Thanks

Comment: You could use a trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking about isn't technically a "relationship" in the technical sense when referring to relational databases. Such relations are things like having a table that refers to the "key" of another table, for instance relating a table with a customer's address to another table with the customer's order. Anyway, that's beyond the scope of what you asked about so to answer your question, you can do that in the application code or a trigger.

Triggers are features of the database that does *something* when an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE happens.

Something like this should work okay with minor adjustments for table/column names:

[image: phpMyAdmin trigger dialog]

```
UPDATE table2 SET inventory = inventory - NEW.qty where id = NEW.id_product;
```

Now that only covers an INSERT; you'll want to create another trigger for Event UPDATE and probably somehow handle returned inventory or cancelled orders as well, but that's probably something you'll handle at the application level rather than in a trigger.

Comment: why i handle it in application??
why not in triggers??
Is there any chance of bug using triggers???

Comment: No reason related to bugs, just easier to program. How are you going to indicate in your tables when an order is returned? -- that's what dictates how you will update the `inventory` count. If it were me, I wouldn't delete the row from `order`, so that limits what you can use to "trigger" your trigger. If, you add an "order_status" then a trigger can run when you update that, but what if a customer orders three widgets and returns two? For me, it's much easier to handle that instance at the application level. It's really just personal preference, you can absolutely use a trigger for that.